# How to resolve this error not enough values to unpack (expected 3,got 2)? for image

Tags: python, image, graph, image-segmentation, vertices

I am new to python programming I was just learning graph-based segmentation and when I am running the below code I encountered an error. code is :

```
    import numpy as np
    from glob import glob
    from PIL import Image
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
    from felzenszwalb_segmentation import segment

    image_files = glob('/content/IMG-0020-00144.png')
    len(image_files)
    image = np.array(Image.open(image_files[0]))
    segmented_image = segment(image, 0.2, 400, 50)
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
    a = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
    plt.imshow(image)
    a = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
    plt.imshow(segmented_image.astype(np.uint8))
    plt.show()

Error is:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-cff61e7244bf> in <module>()
      1 image = np.array(Image.open(image_files[0]))
----> 2 segmented_image = segment(image, 0.2, 400, 50)
      3 fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
      4 a = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1)
      5 plt.imshow(image)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/felzenszwalb_segmentation/segmentation.py in segment(in_image, sigma, k, min_size)
     23 
     24 def segment(in_image, sigma, k, min_size):
---> 25     height, width, band = in_image.shape
     26     smooth_red_band = smoothen(in_image[:, :, 0], sigma)
     27     smooth_green_band = smoothen(in_image[:, :, 1], sigma)
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

please resolve this issue

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.  Where is this error coming from?

Comment: Broadly speaking one of your functions is missing an argument. But as mentioned by @ewong, please provide more information

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether you are passing RGB or grayscale images to the code?
The error is telling you that the image shape is a tuple of just two elements, which is usually the case of grayscale images (having just 1 channel)